# Tagging questions with a tag mentioned in solutions

Tags: discussion, tags

I created [macrodroid](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macrodroid) tag today. There are close to [100 questions / answers](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=Macrodroid) mentioning this app. Cursory analysis :

a) Handful of *questions* specifically mention this app ( tagged a couple of them )

b) Bulk of these , propose this app based solution. OP (s) did not ask for an automation solution (may not have thought of [automation](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/automation) as an option ) but this app based solution was offered ( about 30 % by *me* ).

**Question**

Should re-tagging ( in a phased manner) be done for a) only or both a) and b) ?

I searched site meta but couldn't find guidance around tagging questions which do not specifically mention an app but the solutions propose it

**Edit**  Following guidance here would imply option a) only -  [What are tags, and how should I use them?](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/tagging)

Comment: I'd say just A. If we started retagging questions because of the answers, we may not have a fun time :)

Comment: @DanBrown-  I felt the same later and  I don't know what I was thinking.  In any case, can you convert that into a proper answer to close this please ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tags are for the ***question,*** not considering answers (and they are usually "attached" before any answer is available) – so they should be based on nothing but the question itself. Imagine yourself the question does not have any answer, and check only based on the question.

We're not hitchhiking the Galaxy here that we have an answer (42) and search the fitting question to tag :)

Comment: After editing question, felt the same but thought better to leave the question instead of deleting it , just in case somebody in future comes up with same Q